# Laravel 500 | Server error on UBUNTU 16.04

Tags: laravel, server, ubuntu-16.04, http-status-code-500

I am trying to learn Laravel Framework. For this, I have successfully installed all the dependency like Composer, Laravel. Even I successfully created the project named "blog". But When I run PHP artisan serve, it gives me URL like http://127.0.0.1:8000/ which I execute from address bar then it gives me 500 | server error on a blank web page.
I tried giving permissions to different directories. 
Unfortunately am not getting result, can anyone please help me

I am running all this on UBUNTU 16.04, XAMPP 7.2

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If you add APP_DEBUG=1 to you .env file, the error message should be displayed. Could you add that message to your post ?

Comment: Can you please tell the location of .env file, because am unable to find it

Comment: .env file is located in main folder of you application and make sure app debug is set to true APP_DEBUG=true

Comment: Thanks, guys, in my root directory .env file was missing. I downloaded it from github and generated key and run the serve command. It displayed laravel welcome screen

Answer (score -2):

Try this permission commands:

```
sudo chmod 755 -R blog
chmod -R o+w blog/storage
```

Comment: It might be useful to see the error message first, if you can see and understand the error message, you will be able to solve these problems more easily in the future. Just trying to set some permissions might fix this problem but you should prevent using this as a default possible solution.

Comment: storage folder contains the cache logs of the application, so it must have proper read write permissions.